# Transit in Amsterdam

Tags: transit, ams, lebanese-citizens

I'm Lebanese, planning my trip to Ecuador. A single ticket is almost impossible from Beirut; there would be two stops in EU countries, which would require a Schengen visa. I'm planning to book 2 separate tickets: Beirut to Amsterdam, and Amsterdam to Quito. I will only have my backpack and will transit in AMS. Lebanese citizens do not need a visa to transit in Amsterdam.

What should I do in order to avoid problems, such as not allowing me to board because there are two separate tickets?

Comment: When you arrive at the airport in Beirut, will you already have your boarding pass for the AMS-Quito flight?

Comment: If I am able to do this online.. for sure I will have it

Comment: That should avoid any boarding issues in Lebanon; what airline(s) are you flying?

Comment: Pegasus or turkish airline to Amsterdam (there should be a stop in istanbul) KLM or Air France to quito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Budget LOTS of time for the layover. If your incoming flight is delayed or you have any problems with immigration, you want plenty of time to sort it out.
2. Triple check your Visa requirements. Chances are that you have to leave the international transit area in Amsterdam to go to the check-in counter and check in for your second flight. According to https://netherlands.visahq.com/requirements/Lebanon/resident-United_States/#!netherlands-airport-transit-visa you will need a tourist visa to do so.
3. Contact both airlines and explain to them what you are planning on doing. Get their advice and confirmation that this is okay, if there are any special requirements and any advice.

Comment: Thanks!!
1- This is absolutely true, having Budget for emergencies is a must
2- No Problem with Immigration, I Don't need Transit Visa, and I can check in online already from Lebanon
3- I think contacting airlines is the best solution so far.

Thanks again